# What term is used to mean a prophetic message has a present and future application?

Tags: terminology, prophecy

I am looking for the term that describes prophecy as both present and future in meaning.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). I would say that "prophecy" is itself that term. Beyond that, your question seems a bit fuzzy. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really about terminology rather than about Christianity.

Comment: It could be Christian or biblical terminology.  Isn't true prophecy unique to Judeo-Christian faith and writings?

Answer (score 7):

The term you're looking for is [**dual fulfillment**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_fulfillment). The best known example is the prophecy in Isaiah 7, which is taken by many Christians to refer both to an event contemporary with the prophecy, and to the birth of Jesus many centuries later.